# CAMLQuery on Calculated column returns decimal instead of percentage. How to change to percent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I am using SPServices to query a SharePoint 2013 List and return values across 5 columns.  One of those columns is set to display as percentage, but when the value is returned, it is in decimal format.  How can I change that to read as a percentage?

Here is the segment of code for displaying the returned value:

```
var PercentComplete = $(this).attr("ows_Overall_QA_Percent_Complete").substring(7);
```

Comment: `var PercentComplete = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Overall_QA_Percent_Complete").substring(7), 10) * 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the following is all you were after I'll post it as the answer so you can accept/close this question:

`var PercentComplete = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Overall_QA_Percent_Complete").substring(7), 10) * 100`